# How to append a text only one time using jquery and how to remove validation message once option is changed

Tags: jquery, wordpress, append

I want to append an error message under a select box when next button is clicked if no options are selected. My code is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery(".ladda-label").attr('onclick','onit()');
    },500);

});

function onit(){
    jQuery(".spn").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
}
```

I want the text only to append just once. i have tried several methods mentioned here but nothing seems to working for me.

I have one more concern , how can i remove the validation message once an option is selected.

Comment: but why using setInterval?P

Comment: Side note: instead of `attr('onclick')` use `jQuery(".ladda-label").on('click',onit);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jquery one function](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery(".ladda-label").one('click',onit);
    },500);

});

function onit(){
    jQuery(".spn").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
}
```

Comment: this prevents the click event triggering twice...but if for some reason it fires again (or other event that needs to append the message again) the message will be duplicated

Comment: how can i remove the validation message once the option is changed.

Comment: $("#yourSelect").on("change",function(){$("#yourValidationMessage").remove()});

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean you span first:

`jQuery(".spn")
.find("#error-message")
.empty()
.append("<span id='error-message' style='font-weight:bold;'>Appended text</span>.");`

when the user changes selection:

```
$("your select element").on("change",function(){
    $("#error-message").empty()
});
```

Regards

Comment: it now replaces the select box and displays the appended text.

Comment: I've updated the answer as I don't know where `.spn` come from...this way you I'll have only one message appended.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onit(){
if (jQuery(".spn").html().length==0)
    jQuery(".spn").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

to modify the element only once, you can save the state of modification with data like that

```
function onit() {

    var element = jQuery(".spn");

    if ("yes" !== element.data("modified")) {
        element.append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
        element.data("modified", "yes");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your event on the button click instead of add custom attr with your function...

```js
$(".next-btn").click(function(){
  if($(".ddlist").val() == "-1"){
    $(".appender").html("<b>Please choose an option</b>");
    return false;
  }
  console.log("Select option choosed");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="ddlist">
<option value="-1">Choose</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>

<button class="next-btn">Next</button>

<div class="appender"></div>
```